# Making multiple rows out of single row, SAP HANA Calculation View

Tags: hana

I have this below table

```
  TYPE   ID     VERSION      
  A      WXYZ   a@bbb@aaa    
  A      ABCD   cc@qq
```

I want output like this

```
   Type  ID     VERSION
    A    WXYZ     a
    A    WXYZ     bb
    A    WXYZ     aaa
    A    ABCD     cc
    A    ABCD     qq
```

It is possible to do using Cursors, I have done it, is it possible to do it without Cursor?

Comment: We need to use a CROSS APPLY over a split function but CROSS APPLY is not supported in HANA.  There is a method using query "select T.*, F.* from T cross join someFunction(T.Value) F" which I could not manage to execute successfully. Maybe if your db supports you can try this method.

Answer (score 0):

create table v_test (type varchar(5), id varchar(10) , versionn varchar(100));

insert into v_test values ('A',   'WXYZ'  , 'a@bbb@aaa');
insert into v_test values ('A',   'ABCD'  , 'cc@qq');

select * from v_test

Select * from 
( select "ID" "KEY", "ELEMENT_NUMBER" "ORD" , 
       SUBSTR_REGEXPR('(?<=^|@)([^@]*)(?=@|$)' IN "V_TEST"."VERSIONN"  OCCURRENCE "SERIES"."ELEMENT_NUMBER" GROUP 1) "VERSIONN"
  from v_test,
       SERIES_GENERATE_INTEGER(1, 1, 10 ) "SERIES" -- replace 10 with your max. number of values in CSV-Field
)
where "VERSIONN" is not null
order by "KEY", "ORD"